# Click to copy button not working

Tags: javascript, html, button, copy

A lot of websites have a button which copies text at the click of a button. I found one code [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851) I was trying to make this code work, without any success. What is it missing?

**HTML:**

```
<SPAN ID="copytext" STYLE="height:150;width:162;background-color:pink">
This text will be copied onto the clipboard when you click the button below. Try it!
</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;">
</TEXTAREA>
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>
```

**Javascript**

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function ClipBoard() 
{
holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Comment: In what browser are you trying this? The `execCommand` currently only works in Firefox as it is an editor's draft. You can see this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommandBrowser_Compatibility)

Comment: You should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript
and https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard

Comment: @Jerodev I want it work work mainly in Chrome

Comment: why is Click to copy considered unsafe?

Comment: @AlexR. Then you will have to search for other alternatives.